# Slide down div on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have simple slide down script that shows div on click event. The problem i have is, that onclick event doesn't work if i have it wrapped in another div. If clickable div doesn't have any parent div it works fine.

I'm using this for multiple div's, where only one is opened at once.

I need open 1 to work

**[Here's Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gtucj7zk/7/)**

HTML

```
<div>
  <div class="clickMore">open 1</div>
</div>

<div class="clickMore">open 2</div>
<div class="showMore" style="display:none;">
  <div>text</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
 $(function() {
  $('.clickMore').on('click', function() {
    $('.showMore').not($(this).next('.showMore')).slideUp('fast');
    $(this).next('.showMore').slideToggle('fast');
  });
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gtucj7zk/8/

Comment: Thanks, but i can't change the HTML. I can only change JS. I removed open 2 in fiddle if you can work on that http://jsfiddle.net/gtucj7zk/11/

Comment: What should clicking 'open 1' do? There's no associated content...?

Comment: it should open the .showMore div. The same as  open 2 does. The issues is, that open 1 is wrapped in another div and thus JS doesn't work. and since i can't edit HTML i can't change that.

Comment: Then you it could be simple like http://jsfiddle.net/gtucj7zk/14/

Comment: This works when i only have one div to open. I'm using multiple and i see now that i didn't add enough data to you guys. I edited fiddle so now i think it should be clear http://jsfiddle.net/gtucj7zk/15/ 1,2,3 works, 44,55,66 don't work, because of that extra div in .clickMore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gtucj7zk/18/)**.

The problem happen since you've two cases and the selector `$(this).next('.showMore')` will not return always the desired result, since when you've the `.clickMore` element inside a `div` the `.next()` function will not find the element because it's outside of the current div?

My suggestion id to add a condition to make sure if the related `.showMore` element is directly next to the clicked `div` or it should be targeted by adding the `parent` :

```
$(function() {
  $('.clickMore').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).next('.showMore').length) {
      var show_more = $(this).next('.showMore');
    } else {
      var show_more = $(this).parent().next('.showMore');
    }

    $('.showMore').not(show_more).slideUp('fast');
    show_more.slideToggle('fast');
  });
});
```

Short version of condition could be :

```
$(function() {
  $('.clickMore').on('click', function() {
    var show_more = $(this).next('.showMore');
    show_more = show_more.length > 0 ? show_more : $(this).parent().next('.showMore');

    $('.showMore').not(show_more).slideUp('fast');
    show_more.slideToggle('fast');
  });
});
```

Comment: Awesome...this is exactly how i wanted. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(function() {
  $('.clickMore').on('click', function() {
    $('.showMore').slideToggle('fast');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gtucj7zk/19/)

```
$(function() {
  $('.clickMore').on('click', function() {   
    $('.showMore').hide();
    var el = $(".showMore");    
    $(".showMore").remove();
    $(this).append(el);
    $('.showMore').slideToggle();
  });
});
```

You are able to change the text content dynamically